# Can I configure Jupyter to open notebooks via links on webpages?

Tags: browser, jupyter-notebook

I use Jupyter notebooks (with the Python kernel) for my teaching. I often post my notebooks on our university's Moodle platform for my students to use. When they click a link to a notebook, they have to first save the notebook locally and then open it from the Jupyter interface.

Is there a way to configure Jupyter and/or my browser to open the notebook directly in Jupyter instead of having to download it first and then open it manually afterwards? I do not mind if this requires having started Jupyter first, running in another tab in the browser.

I am using Firefox on Linux, but ideally I am looking for a solution that will work in any or most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I use JupyterHub for my courses, and have some custom "services" for such utilities. But an easier solution for you might be to have the students download the notebook from inside a running notebook (such as your syllabus). We have also developed a %download magic for making that easy. But you can download a URL fairly easily, depending on the Jupyter language you are using.

Download magic: https://github.com/Calysto/metakernel/blob/master/metakernel/magics/README.md#download

Requires metakernel, and metakernel.register_ipython_magics()